# Can't added "it" blocks inside "if" statement in Jasmine JS script

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I want to manipulate if statement for 2 possible dynamic cases,

But also I need to separate my "it" blocks in order to keep a capturing the current screen by my HTML Reporter.

So my only possible option for this case is to manipulate if statement above the flows of the "it" blocks.

**The code:**

```
describe('LiveSite Portal - Existing client send new message', function() {

    var msgBtn = element(by.xpath("//div[@class='actions-row']//a[.='Leave Your Details']"));
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

    it('LiveSite - Home Page', function() {
       liveSiteHome();
    });

    if (msgBtn.isPresent() === true) {

        it('LiveSite Portal - Existing client send new message - Message form', function() {
          browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(msgBtn), 10000);
          element(msgBtn).click();
          waitPageToLoad(); 
          expect(element(by.id("new_client_message_message")).isPresent()).toBe(true);
          element(by.css("div.row.mandatory > div.area")).click();
          element(by.id("new_client_message_title")).sendKeys("Automation message");
          element(by.id("new_client_message_message")).sendKeys("I am not logged-in client. Please call me.");
          element(by.id("new_client_message_email")).sendKeys("idanvcita@gmail.com");
        });

        it('LiveSite Portal - Existing client send new message - Welcome back for existing client', function() {
          element(by.id("new_client_message_first_name")).click();
          browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.css("span.welcome-back"))), 10000);
          expect(element(by.css("span.welcome-back")).isPresent()).toBe(true);
        });

        it('LiveSite Portal - Existing client send new message - Messeage Sent', function() {
          element(by.name("commit")).click();
          waitPageToLoad(); 
          expect(element(by.css(".final-container")).isPresent()).toBe(true);
        });

        it('LiveSite Portal - Existing client send new message - Back to home page', function() {
          element(by.css(".standard-button")).click();
          expect(element(by.model("email")).isPresent()).toBe(true);
          browser.driver.sleep(2000);
        });

    } else {

        it('LiveSite Portal - Send new message from the text box - Text Area', function() {
          // expect(element(msgBox.isPresent()).toBe(true);
          element(by.xpath("//div[@id='main_container']/main/div/div/section/div[2]/div/div[2]/footer/form/div[2]/textarea")).sendKeys("Hello!\nHow are you?\nHave a good day! :)");
        });

        it('LiveSite Portal - Send new message from the text box - Message has been sent', function() {
          element(by.xpath("//div[@id='main_container']//button[.='Send']")).click();
          browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.xpath("//div[@id='main_container']//h2[.='Quick conversation']"))), 10000);
          browser.driver.sleep(2000);
        });
      }
});
```

**The error:**

```
c:\automation\tests>protractor conf.js
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
LiveSite Portal - Existing client send new message
  LiveSite - Home Page - pass
  LiveSite Portal - Send new message from the text box - Text Area - fail
  LiveSite Portal - Send new message from the text box - Message has been sent -
 fail


Failures:

  1) LiveSite Portal - Existing client send new message LiveSite Portal - Send n
ew message from the text box - Text Area
   Message:
     ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=43.0.2357.81)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9
cf),platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any sta
cktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 31 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'vCitaQA', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arc
h: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEn
abled=false, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\idan\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir1204
_19371}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, vers
ion=43.0.2357.81, platform=WIN8_1, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=
true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true,
browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEn
abled=true}]
Session ID: 13c4f345d191f957a186dcefef2e9703
   Stacktrace:
     ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=43.0.2357.81)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9
cf),platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any sta
cktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 31 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'vCitaQA', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arc
h: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEn
abled=false, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\idan\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir1204
_19371}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, vers
ion=43.0.2357.81, platform=WIN8_1, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=
true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true,
browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEn
abled=true}]
Session ID: 13c4f345d191f957a186dcefef2e9703
    at new bot.Error (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\
node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:113:18)
    at Object.bot.response.checkResponse (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node
_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\response.js:106:9)

    at C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\se
lenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:377:20
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Ro
aming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\
promise.js:1877:20)
    at [object Object].promise.Callback_.goog.defineClass.notify (C:\Users\idan\
AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\
webdriver\promise.js:2464:25)
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\np
m\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.
js:563:12)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.goog.array.forEach (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\array\array.js:203:43)
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notifyAll_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming
\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promi
se.js:552:16)
    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:125:21)
Error
    at [object Object].ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Ro
aming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:403:21)
    at [object Object].self.(anonymous function) [as sendKeys] (C:\Users\idan\Ap
pData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:76:19)
    at [object Object].self.(anonymous function) [as sendKeys] (C:\Users\idan\Ap
pData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:733:11)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (c:\automation\tests\message.js:45:127)
    at C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\ja
sminewd\index.js:94:14
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Ro
aming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\
promise.js:1877:20)
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\
Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdrive
r\promise.js:1755:8)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:2056:12)
    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:125:21)
    at runMicrotasksCallback (node.js:337:7)
From: Task: Asynchronous test function: it()
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd\index.js:93:33)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\async-callback.js:45:37)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Block.execute (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\
node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:1174:1
7)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.next_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2209:31)

    at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.start (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2162:8)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Spec.execute (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\n
ode_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2503:14
)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.next_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2209:31)

    at onComplete (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\nod
e_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2205:18)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Spec.finish (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2477:5)
    at [object Object].onComplete (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2504:10)==== asyn
c task ====
Error
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (c:\automation\tests\message.js:43:9)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\
node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:913:21
)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\n
ode_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:898:15)

    at describe (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_
modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:658:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\automation\tests\message.js:1:63)

  2) LiveSite Portal - Existing client send new message LiveSite Portal - Send n
ew message from the text box - Message has been sent
   Message:
     ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=43.0.2357.81)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9
cf),platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any sta
cktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 22 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'vCitaQA', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arc
h: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEn
abled=false, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\idan\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir1204
_19371}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, vers
ion=43.0.2357.81, platform=WIN8_1, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=
true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true,
browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEn
abled=true}]
Session ID: 13c4f345d191f957a186dcefef2e9703
   Stacktrace:
     ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=43.0.2357.81)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9
cf),platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any sta
cktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 22 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
System info: host: 'vCitaQA', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arc
h: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEn
abled=false, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\idan\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir1204
_19371}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, vers
ion=43.0.2357.81, platform=WIN8_1, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=
true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true,
browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEn
abled=true}]
Session ID: 13c4f345d191f957a186dcefef2e9703
    at new bot.Error (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\
node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:113:18)
    at Object.bot.response.checkResponse (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node
_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\response.js:106:9)

    at C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\se
lenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:377:20
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Ro
aming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\
promise.js:1877:20)
    at [object Object].promise.Callback_.goog.defineClass.notify (C:\Users\idan\
AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\
webdriver\promise.js:2464:25)
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\np
m\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.
js:563:12)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.goog.array.forEach (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\array\array.js:203:43)
    at [object Object].promise.Promise.notifyAll_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming
\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promi
se.js:552:16)
    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:125:21)
Error
    at [object Object].ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Ro
aming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:403:21)
    at [object Object].self.(anonymous function) [as click] (C:\Users\idan\AppDa
ta\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:76:19)
    at [object Object].self.(anonymous function) [as click] (C:\Users\idan\AppDa
ta\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:733:11)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (c:\automation\tests\message.js:49:78)
    at C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\ja
sminewd\index.js:94:14
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Ro
aming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\
promise.js:1877:20)
    at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\
Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdrive
r\promise.js:1755:8)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:2056:12)
    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:125:21)
    at runMicrotasksCallback (node.js:337:7)
From: Task: Asynchronous test function: it()
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd\index.js:93:33)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\async-callback.js:45:37)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Block.execute (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\
node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:1174:1
7)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.next_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2209:31)

    at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.start (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2162:8)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Spec.execute (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\n
ode_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2503:14
)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.next_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2209:31)

    at onComplete (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\nod
e_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2205:18)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Spec.finish (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2477:5)
    at [object Object].onComplete (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2504:10)==== asyn
c task ====
Error
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (c:\automation\tests\message.js:48:9)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe_ (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\
node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:913:21
)
    at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\n
ode_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:898:15)

    at describe (C:\Users\idan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_
modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:658:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\automation\tests\message.js:1:63)

Finished in 9.907 seconds
3 tests, 3 assertions, 2 failures

[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] chrome #1 failed 2 test(s)
[launcher] overall: 2 failed spec(s)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1

c:\automation\tests>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to split your tests in 2 describe sequences with beforeEach ?

Something like that :

```
describe('LiveSite Portal - Existing client send new message', function() {

    var msgBtn = element(by.xpath("//div[@class='actions-row']//a[.='Leave Your Details']"));
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    var msgBtniIsPresent = true;

    it('LiveSite - Home Page', function() {
        liveSiteHome();
    });

    describe('With msgBtn.isPresent()', function() {
        beforeEach(function(done) {
            msgBtn.isPresent().then(function(isPresent) {
                msgBtniIsPresent = isPresent;
                done();
            });
        });

        if (msgBtniIsPresent) {

            it('LiveSite Portal - Existing client send new message - Message form', function() {
                browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(msgBtn), 10000);
                element(msgBtn).click();
                waitPageToLoad();
                expect(element(by.id("new_client_message_message")).isPresent()).toBe(true);
                element(by.css("div.row.mandatory > div.area")).click();
                element(by.id("new_client_message_title")).sendKeys("Automation message");
                element(by.id("new_client_message_message")).sendKeys("I am not logged-in client. Please call me.");
                element(by.id("new_client_message_email")).sendKeys("idanvcita@gmail.com");
            });

            it('LiveSite Portal - Existing client send new message - Welcome back for existing client', function() {
                element(by.id("new_client_message_first_name")).click();
                browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.css("span.welcome-back"))), 10000);
                expect(element(by.css("span.welcome-back")).isPresent()).toBe(true);
            });

            it('LiveSite Portal - Existing client send new message - Messeage Sent', function() {
                element(by.name("commit")).click();
                waitPageToLoad();
                expect(element(by.css(".final-container")).isPresent()).toBe(true);
            });

            it('LiveSite Portal - Existing client send new message - Back to home page', function() {
                element(by.css(".standard-button")).click();
                expect(element(by.model("email")).isPresent()).toBe(true);
                browser.driver.sleep(2000);
            });

        } else {

            describe('With msgBtn.isPresent() === false', function() {
                it('LiveSite Portal - Send new message from the text box - Text Area', function() {
                    // expect(element(msgBox.isPresent()).toBe(true);
                    element(by.xpath("//div[@id='main_container']/main/div/div/section/div[2]/div/div[2]/footer/form/div[2]/textarea")).sendKeys("Hello!\nHow are you?\nHave a good day! :)");
                });

                it('LiveSite Portal - Send new message from the text box - Message has been sent', function() {
                    element(by.xpath("//div[@id='main_container']//button[.='Send']")).click();
                    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.xpath("//div[@id='main_container']//h2[.='Quick conversation']"))), 10000);
                    browser.driver.sleep(2000);
                });
            });

        }
    });
});
```

You could also manually trigger some screenshots when needed, by using

```
 browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(png) {
     // Do something with the png...
 };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it doesn't solve my problem. 
the actual error now is about it doesn't recognize any elements in the script. and of course I aware for  the function of taking capture but I can't present the captured images inside the HTML report so It's not a possible option for me. @Paqman

Answer (score 0):

A way around this is to not have the `if` at all. Looking at the descriptions of the tests, it looks like you have different tests running depending whether the user is an existing client or not (whatever that means for your business use-case). I would have a set of tests for an existing client, and a set of tests for a new client, and always run both. You might have to login as different users / actually create different users as part of the test, but that's fine (and by my understanding, quite standard).

I would also argue this isn't just a workaround, it's an improvement. You have a constant set of tests, with each test always running, and so always failing if something breaks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Michal, but in this case I want to use this test script no matter if the user is existing or not, because if he's exisiting ther some element that should change another element in the UI. So the rational of this script it should run for both of the cases because it should be a dynamic test. I need to manipulate "IF" statement in this case. but is very wired that it failure all the time.. :/ @Michal Charemza

Comment: @IdanE Understood that the UI is different depending if the users exists or not. My suggestion is to always test those 2 cases, one with a user that exists, and one that doesn't.